# break - предложение с меткой в Java11

Tags: if, операторы, java-11, break

Какое значение переменной `x` выведет на консоль следующая простая программа, и почему?

```
import java.io.*;

class TestBreakWIthLabel
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int x = 1;

        L:if ( x++ < 2 ) break L;

        System.out.println( "x = " + x );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Фактически `break`-предложение с меткой играет роль предложения `goto` в других языках. Единственное отличие состоит в том, что break-предложение с меткой должно передавать управление на предложение с меткой, которое содержит в себе исходное break-предложение.

При этом как только предложение с меткой получает управление оно сразу же нормально завершается.

Согласно спецификация языка Java 11 (14.15 The break Statement)

> A break statement with label Identifier attempts to transfer control
>   to the enclosing  labeled statement (§14.7) that has the same
>   Identifier as its label; **this statement,  which is called the break
>   target, then immediately completes normally**. In this case,  the break
>   target need not be a switch, while, do, or for statement.

Следовательно, при первом (и единственном) выполнении if-предложения будет  выполняться его под-предложение с `break`. При этом переменная `x` увеличится на `1` и будет равна `2`.

Предложение `break` передает управление на предложение `if`, которое моментально завершается, то есть его условие повторно не вычисляется заново.

В итоге `x` будет равно `2`.

Comment: `statement` - утверждение. На русский обычно переводят как `оператор`, несмотря на то, что у термина `operator` совсем другое значение. Соответственно `break statement` - `оператор break`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92839/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-vlad-from-moscow).